# MySQL: is it possible to format UNIXTIME within a result table?

Tags: php, mysql, time, iso, date-format

everyone. I am brand new to SQL and I am using it within a Drupal instalation. I would like to know if it is possible to format the results I get (in UNIXTIME) into a DATE TIME format (human-readable, DD-MM-YY, or ISO time with a little twist, since I am not in USA) within the query itself.

So far, this is my very simple query:

```
SELECT name, mail, login, status AS activo
FROM users
WHERE status = '1'
AND login > '0'
```

Is there a way to format my "login" column from UNIXTIME to ISO time?

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, what worked for me was:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME (login, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_login
```

but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed - see [MySQL Date and time functions: date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).
eg.

```
SELECT name, 
       mail, 
       date_format(login,'%d %M %Y %k:%i:%s') as formatted_login, 
       status AS activo
FROM users
WHERE status = '1'
AND login > '0'
```

Comment: Thank you SO very much, Mark. I'll try this. :)
---

hmmm... i am getting NULL values.


`name mail formatted_login activo`
`admin ***@gmail.com NULL 1`
`gg ***@***.com NULL 1`
`sofia sofia@***net NULL 1`
`ania ania@***.net NULL 1`
`Soluciones *** soluciones@***.com NULL 1`

Comment: DATE_FORMAT() uses a mysql datetime as a input - if the data is a Unix timestamp you'll need to convert it first .... DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(login),'%d %M %Y %k:%i:%s')

Comment: Actually, what worked for me was:

    FROM_UNIXTIME (login, '%Y-%m-%d') AS formatted_login

but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Mark.

This was my final query:
SELECT name, mail, FROM_UNIXTIME (login,  '%d-%m-%y / %h:%i %p') AS 'fecha de login', FROM_UNIXTIME (created,  '%d-%m-%y / %h:%i %p') AS 'fecha de registro', status AS activo
FROM users

Comment: Would you care to leave some more constructive feedback, Col. Shrapnel?